# What is the difference between Multi-threaded Step and Local Partitioning in spring batch?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-batch, partitioning

I've the following [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/scalability.html).

And there are mentioned that:

> 1.1. Multi-threaded Step The simplest way to start parallel processing is to add a TaskExecutor to your Step configuration.
>
> When using java configuration, a TaskExecutor can be added to the step
>   as shown in the following example:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
}

@Bean
public Step sampleStep(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("sampleStep")
                                .<String, String>chunk(10)
                                .reader(itemReader())
                                .writer(itemWriter())
                                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                                .build();
}
```

> The result of the above configuration is that the Step executes by
>   reading, processing, and writing each chunk of items (each commit
>   interval) in a separate thread of execution. Note that this means
>   there is no fixed order for the items to be processed, and a chunk
>   might contain items that are non-consecutive compared to the
>   single-threaded case. In addition to any limits placed by the task
>   executor (such as whether it is backed by a thread pool), there is a
>   throttle limit in the tasklet configuration which defaults to 4. You
>   may need to increase this to ensure that a thread pool is fully
>   utilized.

But before I thought that it should be achieved by local partitioning and I should provide a partitioner which say how to divide data into pieces. Multi-threaded Step should do it automatically.

### Question

Could you explain how does it work ? How can I manage it besides the thread number?  Will it work for flat file?

### P.S.

I created the example:

```
@Configuration
public class MultithreadedStepConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private ToLowerCasePersonProcessor toLowerCasePersonProcessor;

    @Autowired
    private DbPersonWriter dbPersonWriter;

    @Value("${app.single-file}")
    Resource resources;

    @Bean
    public Job job(Step databaseToDataBaseLowercaseSlaveStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myMultiThreadedJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(csvToDataBaseSlaveStep())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    private Step csvToDataBaseSlaveStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("csvToDatabaseStep")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(50)
                .reader(csvPersonReaderMulti())
                .processor(toLowerCasePersonProcessor)
                .writer(dbPersonWriter)
                .taskExecutor(jobTaskExecutorMultiThreaded())
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader csvPersonReaderMulti() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder()
                .name("csvPersonReaderSplitted")
                .resource(resources)
                .delimited()
                .names(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"})
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
                    setTargetType(Person.class);
                }})
                .saveState(false)
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor jobTaskExecutorMultiThreaded() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        // there are 21 sites currently hence we have 21 threads
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(30);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(25);
        taskExecutor.setThreadGroupName("multi-");
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("multi-");
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

And it really works according the log but I want to know details. Is it better than self written partitioner ?

Answer (score 1):

There is basically fundamental differences here when you use multi-threaded steps and partitions.

Multi-threaded steps are single process so it is not a good idea to use this if you have persisted state for processor/writer. However say if you just generating a report without saving anything this is a good choice.

As you have mentioned say you want to process a flat file and say you want store the records in DB then you can use remote chunking concept assuming your reader is not heavy.

Partitioner will create separate process for a each set of data you can use logically divide.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you are talking about REMOTE partitioning. I am speaking about LOCAL partitioning

Answer (score 1):

based on my understanding, partition is typically used for remote processing.  Partition master (or manager) step will create multiple identical workers. The number of works are the given grid size. For local processing, those workers are identical, meaning the same reader, writer objects, but execute on different thread with different chunks of input provided by the customized partitioner. However, if the worker step has listeners, before/after step methods, those methods will be call by each worker; on the contrary, those method get called only once in multi-thread step scheme. Other than that, I don't see any differences for local processing.

I personally suggest don't use partition for local processing, use multi-thread step instead. There are so many open source packages, don't use them if you don't feel comfortable.